# No sound from usb device in android

Tags: android, linux, audiotrack, uvc

I have connected a usb device(uvc) to my android device. when the usb device is connected the file dev/video0  gets created and iam able to display the video by reading the dev/video0 file .  now iam trying to read the audio data , two files controlC0 and PCMC0D0c are getting created in dev/snd folder . Can anyone please tell me how to play the content that is in PCMC0D0c ?  thankyou

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions not general computing issues. Please review the help on [what topics can be asked on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Iam writing an android  application to play video and audio from usb device .Iam looking for some help in that direction.